# figuring out which theme am I running under Debian-mate?

Tags: theme, mate-desktop, gtk3, gtk2

I have 2 desktops, GNOME and MATE.

As far as I know the GNOME 3 theme lives under [~/.config/gtk-3.0

On right-click > Change Desktop background > Appearances and Themes > It's menta with some customizations which is part of mate-themes and it's at 3.20.7-1 on Debian unstable/sid. This shows Menta look with some modifications. Menta is both a 2.0 and 3.0 look/theme.

```
 [/usr/share/themes/Menta] 
└─[$] ls                                                         
cinnamon  emerald  gtk-2.0  gtk-3.0  index.theme  metacity-1  README  unity  xfwm4 

[~/.config/gtk-3.0]

[$] cat settings.ini                                                                                                      
[Settings]
gtk-theme-name=AlaDelta
gtk-icon-theme-name=matefaenzagray
gtk-font-name=Sans 12
gtk-cursor-theme-name=DMZ-Black
gtk-cursor-theme-size=48
gtk-toolbar-style=GTK_TOOLBAR_BOTH_HORIZ
gtk-toolbar-icon-size=GTK_ICON_SIZE_LARGE_TOOLBAR
gtk-button-images=1
gtk-menu-images=1
gtk-enable-event-sounds=0
gtk-enable-input-feedback-sounds=0
gtk-xft-antialias=1
gtk-xft-hinting=1
gtk-xft-hintstyle=hintmedium
gtk-xft-rgba=none
```

Look forward to know which theme am I using.

Comment: Doesn't `gtk-theme-name=AlaDelta` in your `~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini` determine which gtk3 theme is being used? Similarly, the theme set in `~/.gtkrc-2.0` would determine your gtk2 theme. I don't understand what the issue is. But you need to ensure that the gtk3 theme is written for GNOME 3.20 if that's what you're on. Your question isn't clear on that.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do is to simply use the gui.

On your panel go to System>Appearance and click on that.

First thing to come up should be the tool for setting the theme and so forth.  The one in current use should be highlighted in the upper right hand corner of that tool.

There you can customize the look and feel of your Mate desktop.  Have fun exploring.