# where is AlaDelta theme hiding and how do I delete/purge/remove it

Tags: regular-expression, dpkg, theme

I came to know that I have an AlaDelta theme sitting/hiding somewhere on the system. I tried the following approaches -

```
$ apt-file search aladelta
```

with variations of aladelta in some caps, all caps but no avail.

```
$ aptitude search aladelta
```

Also tried various theme packages which I have installed to see if one of them might have this theme but it's a long slog.

```
[$] dpkg -l | grep -i theme
```

Any ideas how to figure out where this theme might be holed up ?

```
~/.themes
```

is empty.

```
[~/.config/gtk-3.0] - [10106]
└─[$] cat settings.ini                                                                                                                
[Settings]
gtk-theme-name=AlaDelta
gtk-icon-theme-name=matefaenzagray
gtk-font-name=Sans 12
gtk-cursor-theme-name=DMZ-Black
gtk-cursor-theme-size=48
gtk-toolbar-style=GTK_TOOLBAR_BOTH_HORIZ
gtk-toolbar-icon-size=GTK_ICON_SIZE_LARGE_TOOLBAR
gtk-button-images=1
gtk-menu-images=1
gtk-enable-event-sounds=0
gtk-enable-input-feedback-sounds=0
gtk-xft-antialias=1
gtk-xft-hinting=1
gtk-xft-hintstyle=hintmedium
gtk-xft-rgba=none
gtk-application-prefer-dark-theme=1
```

This has become an issue as the theme is supposed to be a fork of adwaita and is obsolete by many years. I came to know about it as it started giving gtk warnings as just have upgraded to gtk-3.20 .

Comment: Post the output of `ls /usr/share/themes`, `ls ~/.themes`, `ls ~/.local/share/themes`, and `ls ~/.local/themes`.

Comment: Link to your related question: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/286558/figuring-out-which-theme-am-i-running-under-debian-mate

Comment: You should post the content of the gtk warnings. I'm guessing you'll find a path in there and then you can use `dpkg -S <somefile>` to tell you the package that owns the file.

Comment: Actually while I can share the content of gtk warnings, I don't think that will help in this case .                                                                                            [$] mate-tweak                                                                                                                    

(mate-tweak:14263): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:63:28: The :prelight pseudo-class is deprecated. Use :hover instead.

(mate-tweak:14263): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:73:35: The :prelight pseudo-class is deprecated. Use :hover instead.

Comment: @DKBose here you go http://paste.debian.net/713207/ , the other paths that you shared either do not either exist or are empty. The one I shared has themes from different packages, xfce-themes, mate-themes, gnome-standard-themes to name some of the packages involved.

Comment: Looks like it's a Mate theme according to http://git.mate-desktop.org/mate-themes/diff/desktop-themes?id=fbcedcbc4860719b398b1ea046187a80ae633438. You really need to clean up /usr/share/themes :) GTK-3.20 is well known for breaking older themes! Even the Arch guys are complaining. Unless you find a theme that's expressly written for GTK-3.20, you're going to face issues. If locate or mlocate doesn't find it, why do you think it's still around?

Comment: umm... because of information on .config/gtk-3.0 . I could purge $sudo aptitude purge <$PACKAGENAME> to get rid of all themes except mate-themes but would like to have them back so that I can use the other desktops when I want to.

Comment: Can anybody give any good suggestions for a good 3.20 complaint theme, one dark theme and one light theme if possible from the mate stable. Also how do I rework .config/gtk-3.0 so that those errors don't show up. Thank you for pointing out that it was part of the mate-stable some years ago.

Answer (score 1):

The `AlaDelta` theme does not appear to be in any standard Debian package.

If you installed it from a non-standard package, you could find out the package name with:

```
grep -il aladelta /var/lib/dpkg/info/*.list
```

Alternatively, if that results in an error message about "argument list too long" or similar:

```
find /var/lib/dpkg/info -name '*.list' -exec grep -il aladelta {} +
```

The package name will be the filename without the `.list` suffix.

If that doesn't find it, it's a local (i.e. non-package) install, perhaps somewhere under `/usr/local/`. If you have `mlocate` installed, you can find out where the theme is on disk by running `mlocate -i aladelta`.  You should then be able to delete the theme's files.